# Is there any Cloud Storage GUI for Mac?

Tags: macos, backup, software-recommendation, ui

On my iPad, I have GoodReader, as well as ReaddleDocs, and both allow me to connect to a large assortment of Cloud Storage providers. On my Windows machine, there are the Cloudberry Lab assortment of products. On my Mac, there are less options.

I have a license for Syncovery, and have been using it since it was called "Super Flexible File Syncronizer". It works great for large pushs and pulls, but doesn't have a great GUI. It also doesn't support as large of an assortment a I would like.

I found Interarchy 10 and DragonDisk. However, the best front-runner right now is CyberDuck, though the GUI is not super shinny.

Am I missing any options? Paid or free is fine, as I don't mind supporting any developers for work they do. If it can have the Mac skin to it, it would be awesome!

Comment: Would you mind providing just a few extra details? What is your end goal with this cloud-connection software? Do you have a backup setup that allows you to backup to different clouds? Perhaps some more info would help provide a better answer.

Comment: I want to be able to manage and upload existing data sets. For example, I want to push certain files to Rackspace Cloud and certain files to S3. I would also like to be able to log into multiple accounts for specific services, allowing me to push work files to work's accounts and personal files to personal accounts. Does that make more sense? It's just a wrapper GUI I am looking for. A one-stop place.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not very familiar with your need, but what about http://panic.com/transmit/?

Answer (score 1):

For my money, the gold standard file transfer program would be Transmit by Panic. Longstanding Mac developers, continued support and improvement of the product, good value for the price if you work with files professionally or have time constraints on your work.

- https://panic.com/transmit/

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it yet, but the folks behind CyberDuck have released Mountain Duck, it allows you to view remote resources as volumes on the desktop (i.e. integrates Azure, SFTP, S3, etc. with the Finder).

https://mountainduck.io/

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Storage Made Easy Mac client. It works with S3 and RackSpace (but you'll need a Storage Made Easy Account)  as well as other Clouds like Google Drive, DropBox etc. It provides an integrated drive (like iDisk used to) as well DropBox style Sync Tools. The demo version gives a 14 day trial: https://storagemadeeasy.com/files/d1cf11a9346404ee4b1921774ece0af4.pkg.

Comment: Can my data be put in my account, or is it stuck in the SME account? I don't know how else it could charge for the space used. http://storagemadeeasy.com/personal/

Answer (score 0):

I use odrive. It's a great sync manager that supports *a lot* of cloud storage providers, like Google Drive, Box, Dropbox, Onedrive, Amazon S3, FTP, etc. You can see the list of providers [on the homepage](http://www.odrive.com).

They offer sync clients for Mac and PC, which both support "unsyncing", where you can choose to just keep files in the cloud. It works really great and it's pretty user-friendly. You can check out their ["upgrades" page](https://www.odrive.com/upgrade) for the premium plans which offer encryption and external drives.

Just note that it probably won't be great for huge file transfers at once because of the lack of progress bars or status. It uses file badging like Dropbox and Google Drive to alert you if something is synced, syncing, or not synced.=

Answer (score -1):

The one I use is called [ExpanDrive](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/26992/expandrive). It's expensive at about $50, but in addition to FTP, it also supports Amazon, Dropbox, Google Drive, OneDrive, and many others.

Comment: ExpanDrive explicitly doesn't support Google Cloud Storage

Comment: Why do you say that?  It's an option when you run the software, I am using the latest version today.   I should state that it doesn't really work well and is as buggy as hell but in theory it does support it.

Answer (score -2):

Cyberduck works just fine with many providers